# In DNA sequencing, is "mate pairs" synonymous with "paired ends"? If not, how do they differ?

Tags: bioinformatics, dna, dna-sequencing, sequence-alignment

By just looking at [Roach et al's paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7601461) I get the impression that they are the same thing, *and* the Wikipedia URL for the former is a redirect to the latter.

However, I suspect they are not *exactly* the same - for starters, they wouldn't have two different words for the same thing, right?

Can anybody shed some light and suggest some references?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paired-end is the name of the sequencing approach.

Mates refer to the read pairs that correspond to the same insert, but sequenced from opposite directions.